# I cannot understand this thing about functions.

Tags: functions

Why do we use f(x) instead of y in functions? I understand it's another way of representation, but why opt for this peculiar "f(x)" symbol?

It seems simplicity might play a role in writing functions, but what kind of simplicity is involved? Couldn't we just use 'y' instead?

For instance:

$y = x^2$ instead of $f(x) = x^2$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By using $f(x)$, you make it clear the function we are discussing is a function of $x$, i.e. $x$ is the independent variable or a representative of the domain of the function. Simply using $y$ may not give you that info, right? Also, $y$ can simply be a constant or something else; but $f(x)$ is most certainly a function. Gives clarity.

Comment: The $y=f(x)$ is due to the analytical geometry representation of a function in the cartesian plane. In general, a function is defined without reference to the geometrical representation: it is an "expression" made of numerical operations with a variable $x$. Thus the general form $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $f(x,z)=x+z$, the value for particular arguments is like $f(2,4)$,
whereas with $y=x+z$ then it would look like $y_{x=2,z=4}$ which is more cumbersome, and only the former signals whether symbols on the right hand side should be considered constant or variable.

Answer (score 1):

"seems simple to me" is a bad argument for anything.

$y$ only makes sense for functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ (or possibly some subsets) when you (implicity) think about the graph of the function. Functions can be from any set to any set, and when e.g. considering a function between two sets of matrices, using a $y$ would feel quite strange.

$f(x)$ also signals a quantity that depends on $x$, when you work with funtions of several variables it is nice to quickly be able to see what it depends on.